# Can you bind the ItemsPanel in an ItemsControl to a superset of the Items collection?

Tags: wpf, listbox, hierarchical-data, itemscontrol

I've been working on a high-performance tree view that's actually based on a `ListBox`. To achieve this, we first start with a hierarchical model where each item implements an `IParent` interface that exposes an enumerable `Children` property.

We then 'flatten' that hierarchy into a list-based ViewModel, adding a 'depth' property to each item. We then use that list as the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox`, using the new depth property to indent the `ContentPresenter` in our custom `ListBoxItem` template.  It all works like a champ and allows us to display several thousand nodes, something a normal `TreeView` would choke on. It does this because again, it's just a list now and a `ListBox` easily virtualizes its containers by default whereas a `TreeView` notoriously struggles with virtualization.

Consider this example hierarchy:

```
Parent1
Parent2
    Child2a
        Grandchild2a1
        Grandchild2a2
    Child2b
Parent3
    Child3a
```

After flattening, it becomes this...

```
Parent1,       Level 0
Parent2,       Level 0
Child2a,       Level 1
Grandchild2a1, Level 2
Grandchild2a2, Level 2
Child2b,       Level 1
Parent3,       Level 0
Child3a,       Level 1
```

Currently, I'm doing all this flattening external to the control, but it occurred to me if I instead created a `HierarchicalItemsControl`, it could do that flattening internally, meaning I could use it for *any* hierarchical model data that implemented `IParent` (or even if it didn't, via a GetChildren delegate.)

The issue I'm running into with that approach is in a normal `ItemsControl`, there is a one-to-one relationship between the items in the `Items`/`ItemsSource` properties and the created containers that are arranged on the `ItemsPanel`.  In this case, there is a one-to-many relationship.

Simple, I thought... add `HierarchicalItems`/`HierarchicalItemsSource` properties, then internally set the regular `Items`/`ItemsSource` properties after flattening.  That would maintain the one-to-one relationship.

The problem there is the `Items`/`ItemsSource` properties are read/write, meaning people could directly manipulate them and that would break the internal logic of my control.

I'm starting to think I can't use an `ItemsControl` subclass and will instead have to create my own `HierarchicalItemsControl` base class, reimplementing most of the internals of `ItemsControl` manually, but I'm hoping there's another way.

### In Summary...

The main problem I'm trying to solve is a way for this specialized `HierarchicalItemsControl` to create several containers per given item as opposed to the one-to-one of a normal `ItemsControl`.

Internally it would ultimately be one-to-one with the flattened list, but externally, I don't want people to be able to manipulate that flattened list (i.e. I wanted to lock-down `Items`/`ItemsSource` to be read-only, but I don't think you can do that since they are registered `DependencyProperties`, not simple CLR properties and AFAIK, you can't change a registered `DependencyProperty`'s accessibility.)

Comment: So basically you just want to [filter the items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view), yes? Plenty of examples on the net showing how to synchronize this with an observable collection including [this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/filtering-elements-in-a-collection-in-wpf/).

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking here.  The TLDR version is I want the panel to represent a different set of containers (one for each flattened item) as compared to the Items property (one per root item).  It's not a one-to-one relationship and is actually the opposite of filtering since the panel will have more items than in the Items property.  Make sense?

Comment: I'll have a think about it and try to post a proper answer, but I still think this is a filtering issue based on what you've said. The one comment that sticks out though is "a lot of that expansion logic is in the ViewModel of the hierarchy, not in the control where I feel it belongs". The whole point of the view model is to prepare the data in a form that the view can readily consume, as soon as you find yourself trying to hit a square view model peg into a round view hole it's a good indication that your view model isn't doing its job properly.

Comment: Consider a Treeview control. The expansion and collapsing happens inside the control itself. The model, nor the view model knows anything about the expansion. That is purely View-related information. If the model needed to know about the expansion, then yes, it should be in the viewmodel, but other than that, I disagree. That said, I am doing filtering regarding expansion and collapsing from within the collectionview but as I said, that has nothing to do with the question at hand which has to do with displaying the non-filtered items. Pretend there is no filtering at all.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm probably going to have to bow out of this one. I've read your description about 10 times and I still don't understand what you're trying to do. It sounds like you're trying to use a ListBox on your flattened list to take advantage of virtualization or something while still presenting a hierarchical display? Yet you talk about passing lists into your ItemsPanel, which the way you've described it is going to break virtualization anyway? Very confused, sorry.

Comment: Here... I'll explain it a different way (based on a different problem.)  Normally in an ItemsControl, the children of the panel (i.e. the containers) are generated one-to-one with the items in the Items/ItemsSource property.  In my example, based on some non-important-here logic, I want the control to add additional children (again containers) to the panel. In other words, the panel will have more child FrameworkElements than items in the Items/ItemsSource property. The ItemsControl would be responsible for tracking those extra objects as they aren't part of the model/data, only presentation.

Comment: So, back to this example, but simplifying it a bit... say I have an interface called IParent which exposes a Children enumeration.  Now say I have a single model/ViewModel item that via that interface exposes four child items. If I then add that single item to the Items property of the ItemsControl, I want the ItemsControl to internally add a container for the root *and* the four child items (five containers total).  The control is responsible for making the containers for *all* hierarchy items based on only being handed the root items.  Make sense?

Comment: I re-wrote it to hopefully explain it better.

Comment: @MarqueIV If I understand what you are asking, it's how do you lock down DPs? Simple, you add a change handler to the DP even if you don't "own it" (via AddOwner) and throw an exception in it if you don't like the change. That being said... I think you're barking up the wrong tree here. What is a human going to do with a tree with 2000 nodes in it? If you don't believe me, do you find Device Manager or Event Viewer or even the left Explorer pane to be very useful? :). It's impossible to find anything beyond the top 1 or 2 levels in a confined space.

Comment: Not quite.  That's just one proposal to solve the actual problem which is a one-to-many item-to-container relationship. As for your other comment, the tree does local filtering and searching in the UI but that's out of scope for here. Still, by the logic you stated, what good is a listbox that can handle lots of items?  The number of items isn't the problem. It's the access to those items from an API perspective.  I'm starting to think it's best just to flatten the list externally rather than having the control do it.  Still, I appreciate the change-handler approach. Something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I'm understanding you correctly you want to bind to an array of Parents and have the control itself expand that out to the full flattened list, correct? So assuming you have a view model like this...

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMainViewModel
{
    // create a list of 10000 parents, each with 3 children
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelItem> Items { get; } =
        Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
        .Select(i => new ViewModelItem
        {
            Description = $"Parent {i}",
            Children = new ViewModelItem[] { $"Child {i}a", $"Child {i}b", $"Child {i}c" }
        });
}

public class ViewModelItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ViewModelItem[] Children { get; set; }

    public ViewModelItem()
    {
    }

    public ViewModelItem(string desc)
    {
        this.Description = desc;
    }

    public static implicit operator ViewModelItem(string desc)
    {
        return new ViewModelItem(desc);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Description;
    }
}
```

...then you can just use a regular converter:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:FlattenedConverter x:Key="FlattenedConverter" ChildrenField="Children" />
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource FlattenedConverter}}"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

The converter itself:

```
public class FlattenedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string ChildrenField { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return FlattenArray(value as IEnumerable);
    }

    public IEnumerable FlattenArray(IEnumerable value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            yield break;

        foreach (var child in value)
            foreach (var item in FlattenItem(child))
                yield return item;
    }

    public IEnumerable FlattenItem(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            yield break;

        // return this item
        yield return value;

        // return any children
        var property = value.GetType().GetProperty(this.ChildrenField);
        if (property == null)
            yield break;
        var children = property.GetValue(value, null) as IEnumerable;
        foreach (var child in FlattenArray(children))
            yield return child;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Checking the visual tree confirms that this doesn't break virtualization in any way, and if you want the converter to respond to changes to the original collection then it's easy enough to modify it to support `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Have I understood the question correctly this time?

UPDATE: So using my previous view model and replacing the ListBox with a subclassed ListBox looks like this:

```
<controls:FlattenedListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

To do that you replace the ListBox's dependency property with a new one and then bind the two together internally with a one-way binding that uses the converter code I posted above:

```
public class FlattenedListBox : ListBox
{
    public new IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public new static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(FlattenedListBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public FlattenedListBox()
    {
        Binding myBinding = new Binding("ItemsSource");
        myBinding.Source = this;
        myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        myBinding.Converter = new FlattenedConverter { ChildrenField = "Children" };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost.  The thing is though that you're still setting the items via a converter, meaning the control isn't actually doing anything. The control is still just handed the flattened list (via the converter) so the control still has a one-to-one relationship with its items.  This is essentially what I'm doing already, that I'm trying to abstract away into the control itself.  Using your example, I'm trying to do the equivalent of that converter inside the control, not external.  Make sense?

Comment: So instead of a ListBox, use a subclass of one (or an ItemsControl) and make the children bind directly to ItemsSource, without a converter (or feel free to add a new property HierarchicalItemsSource if you can find a way to lock down the regular ItemsSource property.)  That's why I think I can't use a subclass of an ItemsControl and have to roll my own from scratch.

Comment: So you're sub-classing ListBox and want the new control to do this without the converter?

Comment: YEs, but again, it doesn't have to be a listbox. ListBox works when you flatten the list externally. I'm trying to create something that flattens the list internally.

Comment: Does it have to use the subclassed control's `ItemsSource`? Because if not you could create a new dependency property (or replace the base one with a new one) and then inside your new control class bind that to the original ItemsSource using OneWayToSource along with that converter.

Comment: That's just it... I'm not sure a subclass can replace a base class's DependencyProperty.  If it could, I'd replace the current Items/ItemsSource properties with read-only variants and do exactly what you mentioned. (That's what I meant with the HierarchicalItems/HierarchicalItemsSource.  Those are the replacement properties that a dev would use instead of Items/ItemsSource as needed.  Getting warmer...!!!

Comment: We're getting there. :) I updated my answer showing how to replace ItemsSource with a new dp of the same name and bind the two together.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I know you can 'new' over something from a CLR perspective, but are you sure that works from a DP perspective?  In other words, if someone calls SetValue and passes ListBox.ItemsProperty, are you sure it won't go to the base class's implementation?  Remember, DPs have different rules than CLR and setting something from XAML doesn't go through the POCO wrappers.

Comment: There are now 2 DPs with the same name but you differentiate between them by virtue of the fact that you have to specify the containing class explicitly i.e. `ListBox.ItemsProperty` and `FlattenedListBox.ItemsProperty`. That's exactly what I'm doing when I create the internal binding. Works in XAML too, if you change the binding to `ItemsSource="{Binding ListBox.Items}` you'll see it breaks.

Comment: Yes, but you don't do that from XAML.  That's what I'm referring to.  XAML doesn't reference them via what they're called or 'newed over' in CLR/POCO terms, which as you pointed out you can differentiate between. But I don't think it properly differentiates between them when accessing them via XAML.  That's what I'm referring to.  Could be wrong, but I think this may cause issues there since the registrations are different.